# How to allow average to be null

Tags: c#, linq

how do i allow this get to be null?

```
public double? GetSignalAverage
{
    get
    {
       var signalaverage = Gsmdata.Select(x => x.SignalStrength)
                                  .Average();
       return Math.Round(signalaverage, 2);
    }
}
```

SignalStrength is an Int

Comment: under what condition it should return null?

Comment: sometimes signalstrength has no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the collection is null or empty:

```
public double? GetSignalAverage
{
    get
    {
       if(Gsmdata == null || GsmData.Count() == 0)
           return null;

       var signalaverage = Gsmdata.Select(x => x.SignalStrength)
                                  .Average();
       return Math.Round(signalaverage, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for a constructive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to declare `SignalStrength` as `int?` to allow `null` values. (If you don't, `int` will be its default value, which is 0.) But even then, `Average()` will simply ignore those values, if there is any non-null element (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358602%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

If they all are `null`, `Average` will return `null`, which you can catch and return, like this:

```
double? signalaverage = Gsmdata.Select(x => x.SignalStrength)
                              .Average();
if(signalaverage == null)
{
    return signalaverage; // which is essentially 'return null;'
}
else
{        
   return Math.Round(signalaverage, 2);
}
```